# Keyboard is not working at apps while I login as root

Tags: 22.04, keyboard, root, configuration, ibus

I am able to write in terminal and search bar at the search apps when I login as root but my keyboard does not working in Firefox, spotify, burpsuite or any other apps. I am also writing this from non-root user. I don't have an idea if I ruined my configs.

The problem is ibus permission error but I don't know how to solve it.

Here's my OS information.

```
root@amd-A320M-H:/home/amd# lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS 
Release: 22.04 
Codename: jammy
```

Comment: It works actually at the burpsuite, but still does not work in firefox, spotify

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; some environments restrict a *root* user from the GUI as a security measure (*only users should be accessing user-level GUI not elevated privileges; root being for system level changes and not GUI use*) but we don't know what you're actually running.

Comment: hello @guiverc

Here's my os information

root@amd-A320M-H:/home/amd# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

if i need to provide more information (like an config file content) please tell me

Comment: "when I login as root" so don't. We use an admin user. Firefox in snap is sandboxed. I expect root never to work outside that sandbox,